# prop-types array of string is incompatible with TypeScript type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

The prop-types of `list` is `PTs.arrayOf(PTs.string)`, is incompatible with TypeScript type. The `list` props can be empty array.

```
import React from 'react';
import PTs from 'prop-types';

interface AppProps {
  list?: string[];
}
const App: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ list }) => {
  return <div>app</div>
}

App.displayName = 'App';
App.defaultProps = {
  list: []
};
App.propTypes = {
  list: PTs.arrayOf(PTs.string) //<- error here
};
```

Got TS type error:

```
Type 'Requireable<(string | null | undefined)[]>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<string[] | null | undefined>'.
  Types of property '[nominalTypeHack]' are incompatible.
    Type '{ type: (string | null | undefined)[] | null | undefined; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ type: string[] | null | undefined; } | undefined'.
      Type '{ type: (string | null | undefined)[] | null | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: string[] | null | undefined; }'.
        Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
          Type '(string | null | undefined)[] | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string[] | null | undefined'.
            Type '(string | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
              Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
                Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKFEljgAUAVAZzm1wLBzAFoYBPMEmZkqVYADsYSKJnRI4AQTBh63VgG8qcOABtgzGAH4AXHENRJAcwDaAXQqUAvlTQQJhpSrPJ0MAHQAYgDCADzKquoAfHAAvHAAFBp6BvBOAJRxMVqUOkQwAK5QEnChACbAAG5RKCqhAPQV1VQulFQR-hXMYLoo-AByKCAK8fgRopQdZUhyBbowahBgrPE5OvqGZvYtjh1cS4yCwnFwaymbDCz+KFBQfQDymAlMzP4W1uk7QA)

Answer (score 1):

You should change the definition to:

```
App.propTypes = {
  list: PTs.arrayOf(PTs.string.isRequired)
};
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKFEljgAUAVAZzm1wLBzAFoYBPMEmZkqVYADsYSKJnRI4AQTBh63VgG8qcOABtgzGAH4AXHENRJAcwDaAXQqUAvlTQQJhpSrPJ0MAHQAYgDCADzKquoAfHAAvHAAFBp6BvBOAJRxMVqUOkQwAK5QEnChACbAAG5RKCqhAPQV1VQulFQR-hXMYLoo-AByKCAK8fgRopQdZUhyBbowahBgrPE5OvqGZvYtjh1cS4yCwnFwaymbDCz+KFBQfQDymAlMzP4W1v4GyACOBcBEZXSOyAA)